# How to define several markers in GoogleMaps API V3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I've got a problem when a I want to define several markers from only addresses. These addresses haven't got theirs coordinates so first we have to find their coordinates and then set the markers. The problem is that some places hasn't get their coordinates correctly. Some get the coordinates of another place.

An example of what happened, imagine that in my array of places we've got "New York", "London", "Paris", "Berlin", for example. And when I create the marker of "New York", everything is correct except their latitude and longitude because is assigned the latitude and longitude of Chicago, for example.

**JavaScript:**

```
 self.setMarks = function(lista, m){  
        var marcadores = [];
        //We've got several maps, so first we define the map that 
        //belongs the marker first. This works 
        var mapa = null;
        switch(m){
            case 0: //Peninsula
                mapa = map;
                break;
            case 1: //Canarias;
                mapa = map3;
                break;
            case 2: //Baleares
                mapa = map2;
                break;
        }
        //We've got an array called lista with the marker information
        for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){
            var address = lista[i].nombreProvincia + ", Spain";                   
            servicios.getLocation(address).then(function(response){
                //The problem starts here
                let latitud = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                let longitud = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                let mark = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitud, longitud),
                    id: lista[0].idProvincia,
                    label: lista[0].total,
                    title: lista[0].nombreProvincia + "\n" + lista[0].total,
                    map: mapa
                });
                //The problem finish here
                //We add a listener to each marker, this works fine
                mark.addListener("click", function(){         
                    switch(m){
                        case 0:
                            self.getPeninsulaProperties(mark.id);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            self.getMarksFromCanarias(mark.id);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            self.getMarksFromBaleares(mark.id);
                            break;
                    }                    
                });
                marcadores.push(mark);       
                lista.splice(0, 1);
            });
            //console.log("Fin dirección!!!");            
        };
}

self.getLocation = function(address){
    var promise = $q.defer();
    $http.get("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false")
        .then(function(mapData) {
            promise.resolve(mapData);
        },function(error){
            console.log("Error al obtener latitud y longitud: " + error);
    }); 

    return promise.promise;
};
```

What am I doing wrong to get the coordinates from a place not correctly?

Answer (score 0):

please try to follow this 2 tutorials on how to define markers on Google API AngularJS

- http://www.allprogrammingtutorials.com/tutorials/add-marker-using-form-in-google-maps.php
- http://www.allprogrammingtutorials.com/tutorials/google-maps-using-angularjs.php

Comment: Thank you but both tutorials don't help me because previously they have the latitud and longitude for each place and my problem is to get correctly the latitud and longitud for each place without crossing their values.